# VBA to loop through multiple worksheets and return to the first worksheet

Tags: worksheet

I am trying to write a macro that will loop through 13 worksheets and return to the first worksheet after finishing with the last (13th.) one.  I cant seem to make this happen.  Here is what I have so far. Can someone help complete this, please?  Thanks.

Sub LabelSet()
Dim xWkSheet As Worksheet
Dim StrWkName As String
Dim xString As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim SDate As Variant
Dim EDate As Variant

SDate = InputBox("Enter Next Pay Period Start Date (mm/dd/yyyy")
If Not IsDate(SDate) Then End
EDate = InputBox("Enter Next Pay Period End Date (mm/dd/yyyy")
If Not IsDate(EDate) Then End

```
For Each xWkSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    StrWkName = xWkSheet.Name
    With xWkSheet.Range("H6:J6")
        .Merge Across:=True
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinous
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlThick
        .Value = "Next Pay Period Starts"
    End With
    With xWkSheet.Range("H7:J7")
        .Merge Across:=True
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinous
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlThick
        .Value = "Next Pay Period Ends"
    End With
    With xWkSheet.Range("K6")
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinous
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlThick
        .Font.ColorIndex = 3
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Value = SDate
     End With
    With xWkSheet.Range("K7")
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinous
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlThick
        .Font.ColorIndex = 3
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Value = EDate
     End With
   Next
```

' need to return to the first worksheet

end sub

The macro works fine but remains on the last (13th.) worksheet because I cant seem to direct it back to the first one. All the 13 worksheets are named sheets (example: "ACE", "ARS", "ERS" etc.).

Thanks
Ven.